# To Replace dynamic value using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have input field like

```
<input type="text" name="time[23][34][]" value="">
```

name of input field is dynamic. Means it might be time[23][34][],time1[11][33][],time2[45][22][] etc

Now I want to change it to multidimension to singledimension like

```
time[]
time1[]
time2[]
```

I have tried below code:

```
$('input').attr('name').replace(/(\[|\])/g, '\\$1')
```

How can i replace it using jquery or javascript?

Comment: is that extra right parenthesis after attr('name') a typo?

Comment: It should be `$('input').attr('name', $('input').attr('name').replace(/(\[|\])/g, '\\$1'));` If there are multiple fields, then you need to iterate over all fields

Answer (score 0):

this may help you:

https://jsfiddle.net/s033kv43/

```
var attrib = $('input').attr('name').replace(/[\[|\]]/g, '');
$('input').attr('name', attrib);
```

i get the name attribute and replace the brackets with nothing, then set the name attribute.
Dont forget to adjust this code, so its alters the correct input-fields